# Malaysian to re-enter UK after Tier 4 expired

Tags: visas, uk, visa-free-entry, malaysian-citizens

I am a Malaysian, my convocation was on 16 July 2019 and my Tier 4 visa will be expired on 30 September 2019.

I would like to attend my sister's convocation on 16 October 2019 (Anglia Ruskin University, Cambridge). May I know whether I am able to be granted a 6-month tourist visa when I re-enter UK after visited a EU country?

Comment: As stated in 'Answers', you don't need a Visa as a visitor. But it would be advisable to bring evidence of the event you are attending and evidence that you are only re-visiting for a few days such as confirmed hotel booking and onwards ticket out of the UK.

Comment: If you have it, evidence of ties to your home country would be a good idea too, eg job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can go back and request entry without a visa. Ordinarily it should be a simple process, but you having lived in the UK on a Tier 4 and then immediately going back to the UK might raise some suspicion; Be prepared to show evidence of your intention to leave in time.

> Visa Exemptions:
>
> Nationals of Malaysia for a maximum stay of 6 months.

[Source](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=MY&NV=Malaysia&DC=GB&DV=United%20Kingdom&h=6675e09fa9bd5c30bdc3153885ebb6c9b8767a71)